# How to delete last page

Tags: libreoffice

I have document that contains two pages. At first I have table from top to bottom of page. Second page consists of single unprintable paragraph character. I cannot delete that character. I want to have only one page with table. Is is possible? I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> at last table cell, but it does not work. Software version: *4.1.3.2*

Comment: Are you sure that there are no empty paragraphs at the end of document that were running over?  View> Nonprinting characters, CTRL+F10.

Comment: I am sure that there is empty paragraph at the end of document. Problem is that I cannot delete it.

Comment: Hmm go to the top of the blank document and press the back arrow key once and hit delete

Comment: After [Backspace] we are at last table cell at first page. After [Del] we are at second page at unprintable paragraph character. Does not work.

Answer (score 12):

This may not be the answer you are looking for:

As per [this blog post](https://noahlittle.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/delete-blank-page-after-table-in-open-office-writer/):

> Problem: open office text document with tables ends up with a blank page at the end of the document if the last table fills the previous page. Why? A new line character refuses to be deleted on that last blank page.

[Bug #254655](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openoffice/+bug/254655)

> In OpenOffice writer it seems that tables insist on being followed by a new line. This means that you cannot get rid of new line characters between tables. It also means that you cannot get rid of a new line character when it follows a table at the end of a document.
>
> This latter case can mean that you need to reduce the size of the bottom page margin just to make sure then new line character doesn’t get printed on a new page.
>
> What ought to happen is that there should be no new line of text after a table unless you actually want one.

**Resolution:**

Not a Bug. (*Seriously?*)

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it as follows:  Put the cursor on that last undeletable newline character which is on the last blank page. Now change font to size to 1. The last (empty) paragraph will now comfortably fit on the previous page. ;)

Comment: Note:  Lưu Voi Thần's answer is the best by far;  Please upvote it or select it as the answer.

Comment: bisounours_tronconneuse's answer above did the trick for me.

Comment: @patapouf_ai this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can click left mouse to the break line at the bottom of the page and delete page break. You can see screenshot bellow
[image: Delete page break]

Comment: I am not getting this option.. Please help how I will get this option

Comment: This option does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did the following:

1. added an empty row to the table
2. selected the last two rows of the table
3. separed the table
4. cancelled the second table (1 row empty table)
5. went on the following page and pushed the 'backward delete' key
6. that's it: the last page was no more there!